# How do I prevent classes from being malloc'd, allowing only new?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

There are instances wherein I want to enforce calling of the constructor which gets called automatically in new but not in malloc (in which case we have to resort to the placement new technique). Is there some way to have classes only available for new rather than malloc ?

EDIT: Compile time restriction would be preferable (as usual, I guess).

Comment: I can't see a way how to prevent someone allocating memory with `malloc()` and apply a (reinterpret) cast to assign a pointer to type of your class.

Comment: Technically `malloc` just allocates a number of sequential bytes, and returns a pointer to the first of these. How these bytes are then interpreted is up to the programmer. That means there's really no way to inhibit the use of `malloc`.

Comment: Why do you have to prevent malloc at all? Simply don’t use it in C++!

Comment: Why the -1 ? It's a valid question, right ? Just because it's not achievable doesn't merit a -1.

Comment: @manni66 That's entirely the point . I don't want some developer to ever use malloc with the classes.I don't want it's usage in C++.

Comment: Do you need a compile time restriction, or a runtime fail would be enough?

Comment: The question is a bit off: Unless you call a constructor, you don't have an object of your class. You may reinterpret some data as an object of your class, but if you do, you are in UB territory. If you want to create a `malloc()` backed object, you must follow up with a constructor call: `void* backing = malloc(sizeof(*myObject)); MyClass* myObject = new(backing) MyClass(...);` Note that this uses the placement `new()` operator to call the constructor. There is simply no `MyClass` object without construction in C++.

Comment: Never ever use malloc instead of new. That’s the point. So if there are some idiots that program C educate or fire them. Inventing tricky code is not an option.

Comment: This falls squarely within the bounds of **not my problem**. As the designer of a class, you decide what the class does and you document it. You can decide to guard against simple mistakes, but you cannot make a class that’s bulletproof. If someone wants to use `malloc` and placement new, will that make your class work incorrectly? If not, you’re imposing a style guide, and as a user I would find that enourmously annoying, even if I didn’t want to use `malloc`.

Answer (score 5):

There’s no way. `malloc` is fundamentally untyped — it just allocates a byte buffer, and you can’t prevent that, just like you cannot prevent somebody from casting an untyped pointer to a pointer of your type.

Anyway, *don’t try*!
As Damian Conway ([probably](http://comp.lang.cpp.moderated.narkive.com/nWMq40v6/murphy-vs-machiavelli-who-coined-it)) famously said, your code should guard against Murphy, not Machiavelli: prevent users from making honest mistakes. But when they intentionally decide to mess with the type system, they’re on their own. There’s simply no use-case for your question. Don’t waste resources on it.

Comment: Also, the implementations of the C++ `new` operators might call through to `malloc()`, and other library code may also use `malloc()` internally, so it's not advisable to remove the `malloc()` library function with linker tricks.

Comment: @cmaster Yup, I considered mentioning such tricks but since they’re impractical I decided against it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a public virtual interface and a factory method for your class and hide your implementation. This way the class could be created only through the method you provide.

public header:

```
struct MyInterface
{
    static MyInterface *create();
    virtual void member() = 0; 
};
```

private module:

```
class MyImplementation
{
public:
    MyImplementation();
    void member() override;
};

MyInterface *MyInterface::create()
{
    return new MyImplementation();
}
```

Comment: This won't stop me from saying `MyInterface* foo = (MyInterface*)malloc(sizeof(*foo));` anyway. Of course, I'd be invoking undefined behavior the moment I try to use `foo`, but I'm not forbidden to initialize `foo` like this...

Comment: Thanks for this, it's useful but I was actually looking for something at  compile time, if at all possible. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't take that answer as something that you should do, but it may work for you if really needed.

First of all, in *glibc*, **malloc** is defined as a weak symbol, which means that it can be overwritten by the application or a shared library.

You can define your own malloc in shared library, that does literally nothing (returning NULL). And then link it using `LD_PRELOAD`.

```
void* malloc (size_t size)
{
   ...
   return NULL;
}
```

That will prevent malloc from **allocating** memory. 
Now a bit more tricky case. As we know `new operator` implementation can use (and usually do) malloc internally to allocate some memory chunks.

Now for each of your classes you have to overload new and delete operators. Internal implementations needs another custom malloc and free implementation that will call:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void *__libc_malloc(size_t);
extern void __libc_free(void* ptr);
```

or something like:

```
static void* malloc_internal(size_t s) {
    // Wrapper for standard library's 'malloc'.
    // The 'static' keyword forces all calls to malloc_internal() in this file to resolve
    // to this functions.
    void* (*origMalloc)(size_t) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"__libc_malloc");
    return origMalloc(s);
 }
```

Generally i would not recommend that, but if you **REALLY** need it you can try. Remember also that dealing with *__libc_malloc* and *__libc_free* if used wrongly can lead to memory corruptions,

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If the reason you need such restriction is for preventing of using `not valid` instances of your class, you may introduce a member variable and use it to determine if an object was constructed properly.</strike>

```
class A
{
enum { SpecialValue = 123 };
public: 
    A() : m_marker(SpecialValue)
    bool isValid() const { return m_marker == SpecialValue; }
    void doAction() { assert(isValid); ... }
private:
    int m_marker;
};
```

or, for `c++11` or higher:

```
class A
{
public: 
    A() : m_marker(true)
    bool isValid() const { return m_marker; }
    void doAction() { assert(isValid); ... }
private:
    bool m_marker = false;

};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, checking `m_marker` without constructing an object first is undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo That is why I wrote that such solution is suitable to check whether an object is valid

Comment: But it *isn't* suitable, because you're only allowed to check it on a valid object. If you check an *in*valid "object", the program is undefined. (And since it's set in the constructor and never changed, a compiler is allowed to replace any call to `isValid()` with `true`...)

Comment: Yes, agree. Thank you